# Как задать несколько верных ответов assertEqual в django.test

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, юнит-тесты, django-rest-framework

При запросе по адресу DELETE /v1/job/335/ может быть два кода состояния HTTP (409 или 404). Оба не являются ошибкой с точки зрения логики программы. Но в тестах я не могу понять, как указать несколько верных вариантов для метода self.assertEqual. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может есть другой метод позволяющий установить несколько возможных правильных значений?

Код примера:

```py
# DELETE запрос к API. 4.5 Остановка расчёта
    def test_job_service_stop(self):
        comment = {"comment": "because I want"}
        response = client.delete('/v1/job/335/', data = comment)
        self.assertEqual((response.status_code, status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT) or (response.status_code, status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND))
```

> TypeError: assertEqual() missing 1 required positional argument: 'second'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `assertIn`:

```
self.assertIn(
     response.status_code,
     [status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND]
)
```

Можно, конечно, и `assertTrue` использовать, но у `assertTrue` минус, что когда условие не исполняется, то стандартное сообщение об ошибке не очень полезное: `expected Trues was False`. Нужно вручную добавлять сообщение об ошибке, чтоб видеть, какое реально значение получили.

`assertIn` же сам покажет реальное значение, которое пришло.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы. Воспользуюсь assertIn

Answer (score 1):

Просто замените на другой `assert`

```
self.assertTrue(response.status_code in [status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND])
```